# TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, typeerror, discord.js

So i have a discord bot, and i have been forking some code and basically experminting. my synax is right however it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined when i try to make my discord.js bot add a role.

```
client.guilds.get(config.guild).member(message.author).role.add(config.role) // ensure this is a string in the config ("")
        .then(console.log(`TOKEN: ${message.author.token} :: Role ${config.role} added to member ${message.author.id}`))
        .catch(console.error)
})
```

Could someone please explain how to fix this as i am still noobish at this.

Comment: use `member.addRole` instead of `member.roles.add` https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole

Comment: so it would be client.guilds.get(config.guild).member(message.author).addRole(config.role)?

Comment: Now im getting TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.
When it is a role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong, the Role ID Was invalid for some reason, Doing `\@role` did the trick.