# Discord bot mute command by mention

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to add few moderation commands to the bot, but I get stuck with "mute" command:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    description: 'command to mute members',
    execute(message, args){
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Siren")){
            const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Muted");
            const user = message.mentions.members.first().id;
            user.roles.add(role);
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

I've been reading various guides and going through documentation and I keep failing on finding where I have made a mistake or what even causes this error.

Comment: is the ID valid? Looks like this has [happened to someone before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368797/typeerror-cannot-read-property-add-of-undefined-discord-js) and their ID was invalid for one reason or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first you try add role to member id, not a member. If no members mention in message, you will get empty mention collection and try get id of undefined, because `message.mentions.members.first()` of empty collection return `undefined`.

Second, try not use role names, use role ID for this, its more secure. And change your if code from `if (statment) then do something` to  `if (!statment) return reject reason` this will help avoid unnecessary nesting of code.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    description: 'command to mute members',
    execute(message, args){
        if(!message.member.roles.cache.has('2132132131213')) return message.reply('You can`t use mute command')
            const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('21321321312');
            if (!role) return message.reply('can`t get a role')
            const member = message.mentions.members.first()
            if (!member) return message.reply('Pls mention a member')
            member.roles.add(role).then(newMember => {
                message.channel.send(`successfully muted member  ${member.user}`)
            })
    }
}
```